# Vertical scrolling where attribute name row is fixed and horizontal scrolling where left most column is fixed in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview

So far I've achieved this:

[image: result so far]

```
//code on data listing screen with a vertical flatlist


const DataListing = props => {
  const memoizedValue = useMemo(() => renderItem, [props.coinData]);

  const renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          backgroundColor: item?.id % 2 ? '#ffffff' : '#f9f9f9f9',
          height: 40,
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        {/* coin */}

        {item.coin ? (
          <Text style={{width: 150, textAlign: 'center', color: '#000000'}}>
            {item.coin}
          </Text>
        ) : (
          <View style={{width: 150}} />
        )}

        {/* open time */}

        {item.openTime ? (
          <Text style={{width: 150, textAlign: 'center', color: '#000000'}}>
            {item.openTime}
          </Text>
        ) : (
          <View style={{width: 150}} />
        )}

        {/* open */}

        {item.open ? (
          <Text style={{width: 150, textAlign: 'center', color: '#000000'}}>
            {item.open}
          </Text>
        ) : (
          <View style={{width: 150}} />
        )}

        {/* high */}

        {item.high ? (
          <Text style={{width: 150, textAlign: 'center', color: '#000000'}}>
            {item.high}
          </Text>
        ) : (
          <View style={{width: 150}} />
        )}

        {/* low */}

        {item.low ? (
          <Text style={{width: 150, textAlign: 'center', color: '#000000'}}>
            {item.low}
          </Text>
        ) : (
          <View style={{width: 150}} />
        )}

        {/* close */}

        {item.close ? (
          <Text style={{width: 150, textAlign: 'center', color: '#000000'}}>
            {item.close}
          </Text>
        ) : (
          <View style={{width: 150}} />
        )}

        {/* quote asset volume */}

        {item.quoteAssetVolume ? (
          <Text style={{width: 150, textAlign: 'center', color: '#000000'}}>
            {item.quoteAssetVolume}
          </Text>
        ) : (
          <View style={{width: 150}} />
        )}

        {/* trade number */}

        {item.tradeNumber ? (
          <Text style={{width: 150, textAlign: 'center', color: '#000000'}}>
            {item.tradeNumber}
          </Text>
        ) : (
          <View style={{width: 150}} />
        )}

        {/* tracker buy base */}

        {item.takerBuyBase ? (
          <Text style={{width: 150, textAlign: 'center', color: '#000000'}}>
            {item.takerBuyBase}
          </Text>
        ) : (
          <View style={{width: 150}} />
        )}

        {/* tracker buy quote */}

        {item.takerBuyQuote ? (
          <Text style={{width: 150, textAlign: 'center', color: '#000000'}}>
            {item.takerBuyQuote}
          </Text>
        ) : (
          <View style={{width: 150}} />
        )}

        {/* price change */}

        {item.priceChange ? (
          <Text style={{width: 150, textAlign: 'center', color: '#000000'}}>
            {item.priceChange}
          </Text>
        ) : (
          <View style={{width: 150}} />
        )}

        {/* price change % */}

        {item.priceChangePercent ? (
          <Text style={{width: 150, textAlign: 'center', color: '#000000'}}>
            {item.priceChangePercent}
          </Text>
        ) : (
          <View style={{width: 150}} />
        )}

        {/* previos close price */}

        {item.prevClosePrice ? (
          <Text style={{width: 150, textAlign: 'center', color: '#000000'}}>
            {item.prevClosePrice}
          </Text>
        ) : (
          <View style={{width: 150}} />
        )}

        {/* last price */}

        {item.lastPrice ? (
          <Text style={{width: 150, textAlign: 'center', color: '#000000'}}>
            {item.lastPrice}
          </Text>
        ) : (
          <View style={{width: 150}} />
        )}

        {/* open price */}

        {item.openPrice ? (
          <Text style={{width: 150, textAlign: 'center', color: '#000000'}}>
            {item.openPrice}
          </Text>
        ) : (
          <View style={{width: 150}} />
        )}

        {/* low price */}

        {item.lowPrice ? (
          <Text style={{width: 150, textAlign: 'center', color: '#000000'}}>
            {item.lowPrice}
          </Text>
        ) : (
          <View style={{width: 150}} />
        )}

        {/* price volume */}

        {item.pricevolume ? (
          <Text style={{width: 150, textAlign: 'center', color: '#000000'}}>
            {item.pricevolume}
          </Text>
        ) : (
          <View style={{width: 150}} />
        )}

        {/* quote volume */}

        {item.quoteVolume ? (
          <Text style={{width: 150, textAlign: 'center', color: '#000000'}}>
            {item.quoteVolume}
          </Text>
        ) : (
          <View style={{width: 150}} />
        )}

        {/* price open time */}

        {item.priceopenTime ? (
          <Text style={{width: 150, textAlign: 'center', color: '#000000'}}>
            {item.priceopenTime}
          </Text>
        ) : (
          <View style={{width: 150}} />
        )}

        {/* price close time */}

        {item.pricecloseTime ? (
          <Text style={{width: 150, textAlign: 'center', color: '#000000'}}>
            {item.pricecloseTime}
          </Text>
        ) : (
          <View style={{width: 150}} />
        )}

        {/* created at */}

        {item.created_at ? (
          <Text style={{width: 150, textAlign: 'center', color: '#000000'}}>
            {item.created_at}
          </Text>
        ) : (
          <View style={{width: 150}} />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <FlatList
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      data={props.coinData}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
      renderItem={renderItem}
    />
  );
};

export default DataListing;
```

```
// code on data attributes page

const DataAttributes = props => {
  return (
    // container

    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      {/* coin name */}

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          backgroundColor: '#FDE047',
          height: 40,
          width: 150,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          borderRightWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#31313199',
        }}
        onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 10,
            fontWeight: '400',
            color: '#000000',
          }}>
          COIN
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {/* open time */}

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          backgroundColor: '#FDE047',
          height: 40,
          width: 150,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          borderRightWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#31313199',
        }}
        onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 10,
            fontWeight: '400',
            color: '#000000',
          }}>
          OPEN TIME
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {/* open */}

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          backgroundColor: '#FDE047',
          height: 40,
          width: 150,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          borderRightWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#31313199',
        }}
        onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 10,
            fontWeight: '400',
            color: '#000000',
          }}>
          OPEN
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {/* high */}

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          backgroundColor: '#FDE047',
          height: 40,
          width: 150,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          borderRightWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#31313199',
        }}
        onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 10,
            fontWeight: '400',
            color: '#000000',
          }}>
          HIGH
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {/* low */}

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          backgroundColor: '#FDE047',
          height: 40,
          width: 150,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          borderRightWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#31313199',
        }}
        onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 10,
            fontWeight: '400',
            color: '#000000',
          }}>
          LOW
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {/* close */}

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          backgroundColor: '#FDE047',
          height: 40,
          width: 150,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          borderRightWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#31313199',
        }}
        onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 10,
            fontWeight: '400',
            color: '#000000',
          }}>
          CLOSE
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {/* quote asset volume */}

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          backgroundColor: '#FDE047',
          height: 40,
          width: 150,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          borderRightWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#31313199',
        }}
        onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 10,
            fontWeight: '400',
            color: '#000000',
          }}>
          VOLUME
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {/* trade number */}

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          backgroundColor: '#FDE047',
          height: 40,
          width: 150,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          borderRightWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#31313199',
        }}
        onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 10,
            fontWeight: '400',
            color: '#000000',
          }}>
          TRADE NUMBER
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {/* taker buy base */}

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          backgroundColor: '#FDE047',
          height: 40,
          width: 150,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          borderRightWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#31313199',
        }}
        onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 10,
            fontWeight: '400',
            color: '#000000',
          }}>
          TAKER BUY BASE
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {/* taker buy quote */}

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          backgroundColor: '#FDE047',
          height: 40,
          width: 150,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          borderRightWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#31313199',
        }}
        onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 10,
            fontWeight: '400',
            color: '#000000',
          }}>
          TAKER BUY QUOTE
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {/* price change */}

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          backgroundColor: '#FDE047',
          height: 40,
          width: 150,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          borderRightWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#31313199',
        }}
        onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 10,
            fontWeight: '400',
            color: '#000000',
          }}>
          PRICE CHANGE
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {/* price change percent */}

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          backgroundColor: '#FDE047',
          height: 40,
          width: 150,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          borderRightWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#31313199',
        }}
        onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 10,
            fontWeight: '400',
            color: '#000000',
          }}>
          PRICE CHANGE %
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {/* previos close price */}

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          backgroundColor: '#FDE047',
          height: 40,
          width: 150,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          borderRightWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#31313199',
        }}
        onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 10,
            fontWeight: '400',
            color: '#000000',
          }}>
          PREVIOUS CLOSE PRICE
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {/* last price */}

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          backgroundColor: '#FDE047',
          height: 40,
          width: 150,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          borderRightWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#31313199',
        }}
        onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 10,
            fontWeight: '400',
            color: '#000000',
          }}>
          LAST PRICE
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {/* open price */}

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          backgroundColor: '#FDE047',
          height: 40,
          width: 150,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          borderRightWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#31313199',
        }}
        onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 10,
            fontWeight: '400',
            color: '#000000',
          }}>
          OPEN PRICE
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {/* low price */}

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          backgroundColor: '#FDE047',
          height: 40,
          width: 150,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          borderRightWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#31313199',
        }}
        onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 10,
            fontWeight: '400',
            color: '#000000',
          }}>
          LOW PRICE
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {/* price volume */}

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          backgroundColor: '#FDE047',
          height: 40,
          width: 150,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          borderRightWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#31313199',
        }}
        onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 10,
            fontWeight: '400',
            color: '#000000',
          }}>
          PRICE VOLUME
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {/* quote volume */}

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          backgroundColor: '#FDE047',
          height: 40,
          width: 150,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          borderRightWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#31313199',
        }}
        onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 10,
            fontWeight: '400',
            color: '#000000',
          }}>
          QUOTE VOLUME
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {/* price open time */}

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          backgroundColor: '#FDE047',
          height: 40,
          width: 150,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          borderRightWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#31313199',
        }}
        onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 10,
            fontWeight: '400',
            color: '#000000',
          }}>
          PRICE OPEN TIME
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {/* price close time */}

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          backgroundColor: '#FDE047',
          height: 40,
          width: 150,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          borderRightWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#31313199',
        }}
        onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 10,
            fontWeight: '400',
            color: '#000000',
          }}>
          PRICE CLOSE TIME
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {/* created at */}

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          backgroundColor: '#FDE047',
          height: 40,
          width: 150,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}
        onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 10,
            fontWeight: '400',
            color: '#000000',
          }}>
          CREATED AT
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default DataAttributes;
```

```
// then they are imported to home and put inside a horizontal scrollview


import DataAttributes from '../Components/HomeScreen/DataAttributes';
import DataListing from '../Components/HomeScreen/DataListing';



const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const [coinData, setCoinData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    coinStastics();
  }, []);

  // fetching coin statistics

  const coinStastics = async () => {
    const header = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };

    await axios
      .post(baseUrl + coin_statistics, '', {headers: header})
      .then(res => {
        setCoinData(res.data.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}>
      
          <Header/>

          {/* DATA */}

          <ScrollView horizontal showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
            <View>
              {/* attributes for data */}

              <DataAttributes coinData={coinData} setCoinData={setCoinData} />

              {/* data section */}

              <DataListing coinData={coinData} />
            </View>
          </ScrollView>

          <Footer />
        </>
      )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

I am expecting something like this, where I can scroll the data portion vertically where the the column names / attribute names stay fixed but as soon I start scrolling horizontally all the columns should start to respond except the left most one, it should stay fixed along with it's COLUMN NAME on top

[image: what I am expecting]

Comment: You need two `<View />`s side by side. The first one contains only the first column, the second one contains an empty first column + rest, with the same columnWidth as the first view's column width. Another note here is you don't need `position:fixed` for it, you can achieve it with `display:grid`, since it allows two elements to occupy the same grid space. You need two cells. The scrollable View occupies both cells and the fixed one only occupies the first cell.

Comment: I won't post an answer as I'm not familiar with React Native syntax and elements. If you need help, please post the HTML output of your components and I'll provide the necessary CSS to make it work and then you could implement it in your components. [This](https://gist.github.com/vinhhungle/0d686c4559663b274ef742ebc055fbec) might help.

Comment: thanks @a.h.g. Your [link](https://gist.github.com/vinhhungle/0d686c4559663b274ef742ebc055fbec) works for me.